# Digital low pass filter using limited number of coefficent

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, sampling

[image]

So I need to create a discrete low pass filter. For continuous-time $x(t) \leftrightarrow X(jw)$  and discrete-time $x[n] \leftrightarrow X(e^{j\omega})$, the problem is not too difficult. But for digital signal (FFT $x[n] \leftrightarrow X[k]$), I have no idea where to start. To make things worse, the number of coefficient is limited (max 8 coef).

What kind of filter should I look for in this case?

Comment: This is a band-stop or notch filter. What specific kind of criterion do you have in mind? (maximally flatness, fastest edge drop, minimum energy leakage,...).

Comment: I assume it's max flatness (related to butter). But I have no idea how "sample the spectrum" is related to creating the filter

Comment: Do a search for the "frequency sampling method" of filter design and you will find a lot of material. It's none too complicated and a perfectly good method of filter design.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that